# Redmine Wiki text is large

Tags: wiki, redmine

I am trying to use the Redmine wiki and I am having a hard time figuring out how to make the text not look so big. Here is a sample of the markup I am doing. Any suggestions on how to make the text not looks so big.

```
    h1. Best Practices
    ==General==
    * Detailed Names
    ==Python==
    * Tabs Only (No space Indent)
    * CapWord for classes
    * lower_case_with_underscores for functions and variables
    * UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES for Constants
```

[image: Wiki]

Comment: Oh wow I found the problem. I have to have a newline after each of the items.

Answer (score 4):

After the heading h1 must be at least 1 empty line:

```
    h1. Best Practices

    ==General==
    * Detailed Names
    ==Python==
    * Tabs Only (No space Indent)
    * CapWord for classes
    * lower_case_with_underscores for functions and variables
    * UPPER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES for Constants
```